# Adding a JavaScript function to a repeat region in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps

I have an area on a webpage (defined as a div), displaying various bits of information about people from a database. I have a repeat region on the database to produce a new div for each user in the database.

What I would like to do is have a Google map in each of these areas showing the exact location of the user from the postcode stored in the database. Ive achieved this in the first area but only because I am calling the function:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

and so am only calling the function once, when the page is loaded (correct?).

also, as I am passing the name of the div containing the map `<div id="map-canvas">` to the google function, I presume ill have to create a unique ID for each of the areas so the google function knows which div its referring to. How do I accomplish this, and how do I include the 'function call' for each of the repeat region areas so as to create a new map for each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to create a `div` to each(and with different `id` each) map. You can reuse some code like this:

1. Create an object with common properties of the maps(I supose they will have some common properties like `zoom` or `mapTypeId`):

   ```
   var mapOptions = {
       zoom: 10,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN 
   };
   ```
2. Then your PHP loop:

   ```
   $i = 0;
   while (@extract(mysql_fetch_assoc($resource)))
   {
       // Javascript code
       ?>
       var newOptions = mapOptions;
       newOptions["center"] = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo "$lat, $lng"; ?>);
       var map<?php echo $i; ?> = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map<?php echo $i; ?>'),
     newOptions);
       <?php

       // HTML elements
       <?php echo "<div id='map$i'></div>"; ?> 
       $i++;
   }
   ```

Of course these codes are an example because I don't know your code, so you'll have to adjust to your needs.

Comment: so the javascript code youve mentioned above (including the php code), how does that relate/relay information to my previously defined function in the head? The reason I ask is the function is doing quite a bit more than just creating a map (eg getting the postcode, geocoding it, adding a 10km radius circle around it).

Comment: With the max number of display area rule enforced, you could do the canvas creation at page load and the actual address change later (grabbing personal data from an Ajax request for instance). That could save a bit of page flicker if, for instance, you allow browsing through a list of people.

Comment: @Giovanni sorry dude, I didn't get your point(neither of kuroi) my english is very bad.

Comment: The JS object is just to simplify the common properties. Whatever you want to add coming by the DB you can set as I have set `center`. You can also use Ajax but I see no use for that once it doesn't depends on any user action, so you can load it diretly to the body. It will be faster, I think.

Comment: @Giovanni any progress?

Answer (score 1):

You will certanly have to bind each map display area to the Google engine, but once it's done, you are free to change the display area without recreating the div.

Moreover, I assume there will be a physical limit for the number of maps you can display on a single page.

So maybe you could create, say, half a dozen of pre-initialized map areas and use them to display the location(s) of whatever person(s) you're currently focusing in? It takes only a call to display the location from the address.

Comment: This is interesting, I have not think about a limit.

Comment: im looking into @DontVoteMeDown 's answer, but in reference to this, there will never be more than 5 to a page (barring some horrific programming glitch on my part :) )